# What is the vimscript's no operation statement?

Tags: vimscript

What is the [NOP code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) for vimscript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VimScript interpreter ignores colons and spaces, so `:` could be qualified as "nop" command. For example, `echo 'foo' | :` is the same as just `echo 'foo'`.

However, there's a problem: due to Vi compatibility `:|` is forcefully parsed as `:print`, so `echo 'foo' | : | echo 'bar'` surprisingly transforms into `echo 'foo' | print | echo 'bar'`.

To deal with this one can create a user-defined command, e.g.

```
command! -bar Nop :
```

Now this works: `echo 'foo' | Nop | echo 'bar'`

Answer (score 3):

According to the url provided:

> The simplest possible statement in C that behaves like a NOP is the so-called null statement, which is just a semi-colon in a context requiring a statement. (A compiler is not required to generate a NOP instruction in this case; typically, no instructions whatsoever would be generated.)

```
  ;
```

> Alternatively, an empty block (compound statement) may be used, and may be more legible:

```
  {}
```

What about "empty command" `:`

```
func! Test()
    :
endfunc
```

Answer (score 3):

The command `execute` with no arguments is a no-op. Importantly, `:echo 'bar' | execute | echo 'foo'` does not transform to contain a `print`.