# How do I create a dummy autocommand for User?

Tags: autocmd

`:help User` warns about using `doautocmd` without any registered autocmds:

> Note that when `:doautocmd User MyEvent` is used while there are no matching autocommands, you will get an error. If you don't want that, either check whether an autocommand is defined using `exists('#User#MyEvent')` or define a dummy autocommand yourself.

It has an example for how to use `exists()`, but not for how to define a dummy autocommand.

I know you can't just use `autocmd User MyCommand` because that lists the registered autocommands, so you need to do something:

```
augroup PluginDummy
    au!
    autocmd User MyCommand <what goes here>
augroup END
```

What's a good no-action command that doesn't produce any output or delay execution?

Maybe `silent let g:loaded_myplugin` or `silent echo`?

*Similar to [How to define a do-nothing event?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/38932/how-to-define-a-do-nothing-event/38935#38935) but the answers there explain how `autocmd User` works and not how to make a dummy event.*

---

Question was closed, but the answer that's not a valid answer to [the nop question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/29133/what-is-the-vimscripts-no-operation-statement):

@D. Ben Knoble's answer to look at Tim Pope led me to how fugitive defines dummy events: with a comment (`"`).

```
augroup fugitive_dummy_events
  autocmd!
  autocmd User Fugitive* "
  autocmd BufWritePre,FileWritePre,FileWritePost * "
  autocmd BufNewFile * "
  autocmd QuickfixCmdPre,QuickfixCmdPost * "
augroup END
```

Comment: Why don't you use `exists()`? Too simple? Also, why would you waste your time defining a dummy autocommand when you could, you know, define the real one?

Comment: I'm defining a command for users of my plugin to use, so I don't have anything to do in the plugin. I think it's cleaner to just `doautocmd` without condition because in my mind autocmds are the observer pattern which usually is for optional hooks.

Comment: I don't follow your logic. What does your users' ability to use a command have to do with `:doautocmd`?

Comment: I call `:doautocmd User RippleConfig` from my plugin after I've created and configured my plugin's buffer, so I don't respond to that event (I don't want to use the event so my config clearly executes first). Users may register that autocmd to run their own additional configuration. This setup is similar to [how fugitive uses User autocmds](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/bdca58ccc57b8af00f287bddb633efde30a3a0eb/doc/fugitive.txt#L651-L658).

Comment: OK, that makes more sense, now.

Answer (score 1):

I found this out from [Tim Pope](https://github.com/tpope/) using it in `b:undo_ftplugin` scripts to great effect:

The `:execute` command with no arguments is a no-op.

Comment: `:echo execute()` gives me "E119: Not enough arguments for function: execute". Edit: `:echo execute("")` works. So `autocmd User MyCommand execute("")` should work.

Comment: @idbrii the `execute` in the answer is `:help :execute`, not `:help execute()`.